# How to insert text into an input tag using selenium and python

Tags: python, selenium

I'm able to find the element by class name that this resides in but I'm not sure how to select it itself and send text to it.

**Current Code:**

```
editor = browser.find_element_by_class_name('editor')
editor.send_keys('text')
```

**Element I'm trying to select:**

```
<input type="text" tabindex="103" placeholder="" style="width: 444px;">
```

**Error:**

```
File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 347, in send_keys
    self._execute(Command.SEND_KEYS_TO_ELEMENT, {'value': keys_to_typing(value)})
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 494, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 236, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 192, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: cannot focus element
  (Session info: chrome=55.0.2883.87)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.27.440174 (e97a722caafc2d3a8b807ee115bfb307f7d2cfd9),platform=Windows NT 10.0.14393 x86_64)
```

Answer (score 4):

Element that you try to select doesn't have class name. Try

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

editor = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//input[@type="text"][@tabindex="103"]')))
editor.send_keys('text')
```

Comment: When I tried I received this error: `selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotVisibleException: Message: element not visible`

Comment: I got this error and searched it but no dice: `editor = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//input[@type="text"][@tabindex="103"]')))
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:`

Comment: if to replace `'//input[@type="text"][@tabindex="103"]'` with just `'//input[@type="text"]'`?

Comment: `Exception ignored in: <bound method Service.__del__ of <selenium.webdriver.chrome.service.Service object at 0x01931230>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 173, in __del__
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 149, in stop
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 120, in send_remote_shutdown_command
ImportError: sys.meta_path is None, Python is likely shutting down`

Comment: It seem to be not related to current issue. `ImportError` is something different. Did you make any changes to your script?

Answer (score 0):

Try with `editor.click()` before `editor.send_keys('text')` and see if it works.

Comment: The cursor popped up in the correct area but the same error message came up.

Comment: Did you maybe try this with Firefoxdriver or IEdriver?